# How should I write this table in Latex?

Tags: tables, pdftex, packages, pdf, longtable

[image]
How should I write this table in Latex?

Comment: Try to do something yourself first, it's not very nice to ask other people to do everything for you.

Comment: If anything, I remember the tabularray package.

Comment: Welcome. // Start here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables. Next, make your package choice: https://ctan.org/topic/table .

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. if you've some trouble to write your tabular, there are online tools like table generator. You can start with it and next ask for a particular thing you didn't achieved.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tabularray,graphicx,xcolor}
\UseTblrLibrary{diagbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
  cells = {c},
  row{1,2} = {gray8},
  column{1,2} = {gray8},
  cell{1}{1} = {r=2,c=2}{mode=math},
  cell{1}{3} = {c=5}{},
  cell{3}{1} = {r=4}{},
  hlines, vlines,
  vspan=even, hspan=even,
  belowsep=0pt,
}
\diagbox{\xi_\omega}{\Delta\xi_\omega} && error signal &&&& \\
&& NL & NS & ZE & PS & PL \\
\rotatebox{90}{Change in Speed} & NL & NL & NL & NM & NS & ZE \\
& NL & NL & NL & NM & NS & ZE \\
& NL & NL & NL & NM & NS & ZE \\
& NL & NL & NL & NM & NS & ZE \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.6}
\begin{NiceTabular}{ccccccc}[hvlines]
\CodeBefore
  \rowcolor[gray]{0.9}{1,2}
  \columncolor[gray]{0.9}{1,2}
\Body
  \Block{2-2}{\diagbox{$\xi_\omega$}{$\Delta\xi_\omega$}} && \Block{1-*}{error signal} \\
  && NL & NS & ZE & PS & PL \\
  \Block{4-1}<\rotate>{Change in Speed} & NL & NL & NL & NM & NS & ZE \\
  & NL & NL & NL & NM & NS & ZE \\
  & NL & NL & NL & NM & NS & ZE \\
  & NL & NL & NL & NM & NS & ZE \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]